# bad practice importing pycaret from official docs

Tags: python, pycaret

Read all documentation from pycaret and many tutorials and examples.

https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/tutorials

All of them started this way:

```
#For Regression
from pycaret.regression import *

#For Classification
from pycaret.classification import *
```

We hace very strict rules here. We MUST NOT do wild imports and the quality check rejects any code importing modules this way. So we are stuck.

is there any other recommended way avoiding wild imports?

Comment: Why don't you just import what you need instead of using wildcard?

Comment: Can you use ` import pycaret.regression as pr` and then call pr.setup() for example?